# I am not all getting all the urls from the google sheet matching the specific string in Google Sheet with AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I got all the data(372 rows of urls) from the column(first) from google sheet into the object.
But when i iterate the object to match each item(url) with specified text then
in the if else part it just returning 20 records (11 from if part and 9 from else part)

Here is my code

```
function sheetApp() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var Avals = ss.getRange('A2:A').getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
  var range = ss.getRange(2, 1, Alast, 1);
  var ranges = range.getValues();
  var arr_backlinks = [];
  var found_backlinks = [];
  var not_found_backlinks = [];
  var error_backlinks = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < ranges.length; index++) {
    backlinks = ranges[index];
    arr_backlinks.push(backlinks);
  }
  var parameters = {
    method: 'get',
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + 'yyy' },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };
  try {
    for (let ww = 0; ww < arr_backlinks.length; ww++) {
      var actual_backlink = arr_backlinks[ww];
      var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
        actual_backlink,
        parameters
      ).getContentText();
      if (page.indexOf('https://coachfoundation.com/') >= 0) {
        found_backlinks.push(actual_backlink + ' Found');
        Logger.log(actual_backlink + 'Found');
      } else {
        Logger.log(actual_backlink + 'Not Found');
        not_found_backlinks.push(actual_backlink + ' Not Found');
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    Logger.log(actual_backlink + 'Error');
    error_backlinks.push(actual_backlink + ' Error');
  }
}
```

##### Execution Log :

```
9:27:42 PM  Notice  Execution started
9:28:10 PM  Info    Found backlinks : 11
9:28:10 PM  Info    Not found backlinks: 9
9:28:10 PM  Info    Websites not opened : 1
9:28:11 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

I tried debugging by many ways but didn't worked.
How can i get all 372 urls with Found and Not Found categorization ?
Any solution to fix this ?

Comment: Execution time? Show execution logs

Comment: I would `Logger.log(Alast)`.  What I don't get is you filter `Avals` to remove blanks.  Then you get `getRange(2,1,Alast,1)` which could include blanks.

Comment: @TheMaster
I added Execuion Log in the code itself.

Comment: @TheWizEd
I removed Avals and replaced with total no. of rows i.e. 373. But still i am getting 11 backlinks found and 9 backlinks not found out of all 373.

Comment: `console.log(arr_backlinks.length)`?

Comment: `I tried debugging by many ways`.  That statement means nothing, if you don't show specific  debugging information.

Comment: console.log(arr_backlinks.length)=373

Comment: Log `ww` as well. Are the 11+9 links you found in order or are they random? Your `try` block probably  fails and throws the error to the ``catch`` block  and in the process, closes the `for` loop at link 20

Comment: Log ww=20 
and 11+9 i found are in order i.e. first 20

Comment: So something is wrong with the 21st link. See my answer below.

Comment: In case you didn't know, you can accept answers by clicking on the checkmark on the left of your favorite answer. If you do know, kindly ignore this message.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
  for (let ww = 0; ww < arr_backlinks.length; ww++) {  }
} catch (err) {}
```

The loop is inside the `try` block. Any error thrown in the block will end the code. Move the `try...catch` inside the loop and add `continue` inside the `catch` block to continue the loop regardless of any error thrown in `fetch`

```
for (let ww = 0; ww < arr_backlinks.length; ww++) {
  try {/*fetch and check*/} catch (err) {/*do stuff*/continue;}
}
```